# How to have logarithmic bins in a Python loglog plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Is it possible to use matplotlib.pyplot.loglog with log binning?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use the function `set_xscale()` o `set_yscale()` e `semilogx()` o `semilogy()`. If you have to set both axes in the logarithmic scale, we use the function `loglog()`.

Comment: "o"? "e"? Were these supposed to be "or"?